# How can I change value in field using datatables plugin and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I using http://datatables.net for sorting my tables.
I generate json and loading rows in table. For one record I creating custom  with custom class.

```
<td class=""><span class="qty_new" data-id="1">50</span></td>
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "ajax/tables/ajax.php"
    });

    $('.qty_new').click(function() {
        alert(1000);
    });
});
```

This code not returning alert (1000) and I don't know why.

Comment: A JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) of the problem might be useful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `.qty_new` field is being created by datatables after the page has loaded. Therefore you have to delegate the event listener to a parent element. Try this:

```
$('table').on('click', '.qty_new', function(){
    alert(1000);
});
```

Or for older versions of jQuery, use `delegate()`:

```
$('table').delegate('.qty_new', 'click', function(){
    alert(1000);
});
```

I've used `table` as the parent selector here, in your code it should be the single closest static element.